# catkin_make unable to create executable and automatically copy header files to devel

Tags: c++, ros, catkin

when I ran my catkin_make, I understand that it should automatically copy the header files which I included in the main cpp file into devel and create an executable, however, it is not doing so.

The error:

```
Linking CXX executable /home/catkin_ws/devel/lib/mqtt_pub/mqtt_pub_node
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquitto.h
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/catkin_ws/devel/lib/mqtt_pub/mqtt_pub_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [mqtt_pub/CMakeFiles/mqtt_pub_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

Note that mqtt_pub_node doesn't exist. Why is it looking for something that doesn't exist? It should be automatically created. From what I know, the executable should be in devel/lib/mqtt_pub, not sure where did the system think about mqtt_pub_node(directory). If I create the dir mqtt_pub_node and put my header file in it, the catkin_make is successful, but the executable would not be created.

[EDIT] The header files should be copied into devel/include, but on my catkin_ws, there is no such directory.

Cmakelist

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES mqtt_pub
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /catkin_ws/src/mqtt_pub/include/mqtt_pub
  include
)

link_directories(
  /catkin_ws/src/mqtt_pub/include/mqtt_pub
)

link_libraries(
  mosquitto.h
)

add_executable(mqtt_pub_node src/mqtt_publish.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mqtt_pub_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Would appreciate the guidance, thanks!

[EDIT] Error from the solution given by cassinaj

```
CMakeFiles/mqtt_pub_node.dir/src/mqtt_publish.cpp.o: In function `main':
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x1f8): undefined reference to `mosquitto_lib_init'
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x210): undefined reference to `mosquitto_new'
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x237): undefined reference to   `mosquitto_username_pw_set'
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x259): undefined reference to `mosquitto_connect'
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x285): undefined reference to `mosquitto_loop_start'
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `mosquitto_publish'
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x2d0): undefined reference to `mosquitto_loop_stop'
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x2df): undefined reference to `mosquitto_disconnect'
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `mosquitto_destroy'
mqtt_publish.cpp:(.text+0x2f3): undefined reference to `mosquitto_lib_cleanup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/lorawan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/mqtt_pub/mqtt_pub_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [mqtt_pub/CMakeFiles/mqtt_pub_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

Answer (score 0):

With catkin you typically don't need `link_directories(...)` nor do you need `link_libraries(mosquitto.h)` which is causing your issue. With the latter one you are telling cmake to link all libraries and executables to a library named `mosquitto.h`, which is not a library but only a head file.
Try out the following:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  # LIBRARIES mqtt_pub
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /catkin_ws/src/mqtt_pub/include/mqtt_pub
  include
)

add_executable(mqtt_pub_node src/mqtt_publish.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mqtt_pub_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Note that i commented out `LIBRARIES mqtt_pub` line because this requires that you are actually building a library named `mqtt_pub`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply! My initial Cmake file was what you suggested, but it did not work. Which is why I went online to research on possible ways to solve my problem. Attached is the error from your suggestion. It is unable to reference the functions which are from the mosquitto.h header file.

Comment: There is a library missing you need to link to. Is mosquitto a catkin package? If it is, then add it as a catkin dependency. If you are building it yourself in your CMakeLists.txt then add something like `target_link_libraries(mqtt_pub_node mosquitto ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. When using Mosquitto, I had to link the client library in my CMakeList. Basically the libmosquitto.so file, which is the client library.

I added the following to my cmake list:

```
set(Mosquitto_libs
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmosquitto.so
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmosquitto.so.1
)
target_link_libraries(mqtt_pub_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Mosquitto_libs})
```

Comment: That is exactly what I said in my comment below: `target_link_libraries(mqtt_pub_node mosquitto ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`