# Using Catkin with CMake Interface Library

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, catkin

I am currently trying to use a c++ header-only library declared as a cmake interface library within catkin. This library is supposed to be used by other packages in *catkin_ws/src*. I was able to compile all packages with `catkin_make` but not with `catkin build`.

`catkin build` fails within the cmake command `find_package(... interface_lib)` in dependent packages.

Error-Message for the example below would be:

> Project 'testnode' tried to find library 'interface_library'.  The library
>     is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
>     'interface_library'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory
>     containing its code is included?

How do i need to setup *CMakeLists.txt* and *package.xml* files to make `catkin build` work with interface libraries?

## Minimal example:

### Interface Library

File: *catkin_ws/src/interface_library/include/interface_library.hpp*

```
#pragma once

#define RATE 10
```

File: *catkin_ws/src/interface_library/CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(interface_library)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE include)
```

File: *catkin_ws/src/interface_library/package.xml*

```
<package format="2">
  <name>interface_library</name>
  <description>Test interface library</description>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <maintainer email="master@disaster.com">Master of Disaster</maintainer>
  <license>MIT</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
</package>
```

### Testnode

File: *catkin_ws/src/testnode/src/testnode.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "interface_library.hpp"

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << RATE << std::endl;
}
```

File: *catkin_ws/src/testnode/CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(testnode)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS interface_library)

catkin_package()

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/testnode.cpp)
```

File: *catkin_ws/src/testnode/package.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>testnode</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The testnode package</description>
  <maintainer email="master@disaster.com">Master of Disaster</maintainer>
  <license>MIT</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>interface_library</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>interface_library</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>interface_library</exec_depend>
</package>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just come across this problem. The fix was to remove the line `LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}` from `catkin_package` in the file interface_library/CMakeLists.txt.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41293456/11674950) mentions that the `LIBRARIES` line requires that you're actually building a target (and [the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-package) says it currently breaks if the target name doesn't correspond to an installed name), so I guess it just isn't currently written to deal with interface libraries.

Answer (score 0):

older catkin or `catkin_make` uses merged development space but newer catkin or `catkin build` use linked development space by default.

First thing you should do is to separate catkin workspaces from each other in 2 different folder. Then set up change `catkin build`'s workspace to merged-devel with:

`catkin config --merge-devel`

and also manually expand it's search areas to both your main ROS folder (default in `/opt/ros/<your-version>`) and other catkin workspaces which you may use with:

`catkin config --expand <path-to-ros-workspace>`

after that add your projects and build.